# Specific Mac display: inline-block issue

Tags: css, macos, display

I am having an issue with a specific mac that is not displaying a certain website I have built correctly. Every other mac and pc I have tested displays the website correctly but this one specific mac in all browsers on it is displaying incorrectly the issue I am getting is inline block elements are not next to each other, I have all the 'hacks' in place and like mentioned this displays correctly on every other computer.

This question here is the exact same issue but it doesnt seem to have been resolved.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6650689?start=0&tstart=0

I know I could try floats but I would rather find the route of this cause, does anyone know of any reason this might be happening?

Comment: how do you specify the widths of the elements? Maybe it has a different version of the font you use installed with slightly different metrics, resulting in the differences?

Comment: @cello your a genius, I deleted the font on that computer and everything works fine! Thanks for this! If you write an answer I can accept it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If browser renderings vary only on a single or a few machines, fonts are a possible culprit. Make sure all computers use the same fonts to render your page, actually even that the same version of the font is used.

A lot of fonts get slightly modified over time, often the kerning (space between two characters) or the hinting (how the curves that describe fonts should be mapped to pixels on the screen) might change, resulting in very minor differences in the width some text consumes when being displayed.

If indeed the font version is the culprit: Remember that visitors of your page might also have this "bad" version of the font. So it is advisable to try to improve your HTML layout.

I've often observed that leaving a few percentages empty helps to deal with such font issues. For example: having a `div` (width=100%) that contains two elements in each "row", the first one a label of about 1/3rd the width, and the second one being some control, taking up the rest of the space. Having them defined with `width:33%` and `width:67%` often results in the case that the second part is laid out below the first part instead next to each other. Changing the widths to something like `width:32%` and `width:65%` often fixes this, as it allows for some rounding errors in the browsers when laying out the elements.